# HTML + CSS Integration In Codecademy Course

Tags: html, css

I have created my first website using instructions from the old introduction to HTML and CSS on http://codecademy.com

The code works well in the special constructor page, but now when I try to take out into the wild my HTML and CSS do not seem to link up. I try to view in a browser but no joy, I think I tried to upload the files to a file server but still no joy and tried several tutorials.

Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong? is it something to do with the CSS style sheet references at the top of the HTML?

Here is my HTML and CSS code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/shift.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="nav">
      <div class="container">
        <ul class="pull-left">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="pull-right">
          <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Prices</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Computer repairs and upgrades.</h1>
        <p>Fast and friendly services for all your computer needs. Call 07952270940 for a free consultation.</p>
        <p>- PC and Laptop repair to your door</p>
        <p>- Virus/Malware Removal</p>
        <p>- Tune up / Speed up</p>
        <p>- Computer Upgrades</p>
        <p>- Internet Security</p>
        <p>- No-fix / No-fee Policy</p>
        <p>- 7 days a week service</p>
        <p>- Guaranteed work & parts
</p>
        <a href="#">Learn More</a>
      </div>
    </div> 

<div class="neighborhood-guides">
<div class="container">
<h2>Neighborhood Guides</h2>
<p>We pride ourselves on openness and fairness with accurate quotes and no hidden costs.</p>
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
      Laptops
      <img src="http://i650.photobucket.com/albums/uu227/cre8t0r/PC%20and%20Laptop%20repair%20website/photo_39726_20150729_zpsyypbc60q.jpg">
      </div>

<div class="thumbnail">
Website development
<img src="http://i650.photobucket.com/albums/uu227/cre8t0r/PC%20and%20Laptop%20repair%20website/photo_40106_20150820_zpsxs617yvx.jpg">
</div>
</div>

      <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
      PC's
      <img src="http://i650.photobucket.com/albums/uu227/cre8t0r/PC%20and%20Laptop%20repair%20website/photo_40371_20150828_zpsmabjmlys.jpg">
      </div>

<div class="thumbnail">
Upgrades
<img src="http://i650.photobucket.com/albums/uu227/cre8t0r/PC%20and%20Laptop%20repair%20website/photo_41306_20150916_zpsw0mykfns.jpg">
</div>
</div>

      <div class="col-md-4">

      <div class="thumbnail">
      Price promise
      <img src="http://i650.photobucket.com/albums/uu227/cre8t0r/PC%20and%20Laptop%20repair%20website/photo_40001_20150814_zpsk1nnnytm.jpg">
      </div>
      </div>


      <div class="col-md-4">

      <div class="thumbnail">
      Security and virus removal
      <img src="http://i650.photobucket.com/albums/uu227/cre8t0r/PC%20and%20Laptop%20repair%20website/c775776e-19e5-40f4-a651-7d73434ce9d0_zpsr59jga2j.jpg">
      </div>



</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

    <div class="learn-more">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <h3>Laptop screen repair</h3>
            <p>We are specialists in laptop screen repair. We provide screens for all laptops.</p>
            <p><a href="#">I dunno yet</a></p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <h3>No-fix / No-fee Policy</h3>
            <p>Renting out your unused space could pay your bills or fund your next vacation.</p>
            <p><a href="#">Learn more about hosting</a></p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <h3>Trust and Safety</h3>
            <p>From Verified ID to our worldwide customer support team, we've got your back.</p>
            <p><a href="#">Learn about trust at Airbnb</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>








.nav a {
  color: #5a5a5a;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 14px 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline;
}

.jumbotron {
  background-image:url('http://pcmedcenter.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/banner12-1920x600.jpg');
  height: 470px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.jumbotron .container {
  position: relative;
  top:0px;
}

.jumbotron h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 48px;  
  font-family: 'Shift', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.jumbotron p {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

.learn-more {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.learn-more h3 {
  font-family: 'Shift', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.learn-more a {
  color: #00b0ff;
}

.neighborhood-guides {
    background-color: #efefef;
    Border-bottom: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
}

.neighborhood-guides h2 {
    color: #393c3d;
    font-size: 24px;
}

.neighborhood-guides p {
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 13px;
}
```

Comment: Almost certainly a path issue.

Comment: Please use list instead of manually typing in them

Answer (score 0):

Since the third stylesheet's path is relative, you have to make sure the path is correct and you have a main.css file in the same folder as your html file.

Answer (score 0):

Oh man, a few suggestions to help keep you on track!

First off copy your CSS code and store it locally. Create a web project folder and then a themes folder to keep your CSS in.

> C:\web
>
> C:\web\index.html
>
> C:\web\themes\classic\style.css

Also avoid BootStrap like the plague! It's CSS done by server guys and it uses jQuery (CSS is client side, not server and client/server are two different mentalities). You don't need to over-complicate your understanding. Stick to HTML and CSS and "vanilla" (plain) JavaScript as adding dependencies makes your code weak and locks you in to things that you're not ready to understand whether it will benefit you or not (hint: those won't). Most people who use that stuff couldn't code vanilla if their lives depended on it so learn real code first and *then* consider third party stuff per project and only if it fits a given project.

Also understand that there are two parsers in browsers, HTML and XML parsers. You can serve code loose or strict; the HTML parser is loose while the XML parser is strict. Firefox is great for working with the XML parser (save your files as .xhtml) and you can still use HTML5 (it's just HTML5 served XML compatible) but when you make an error (with few exceptions) the whole page will break and you'll get an error message telling you what is wrong which is great because now that you're aware you can quickly fix it and move on.

One of the best resources is Mozilla Developer Network. Generally opt for that when looking things up. Beyond that focus on what *you* want to achieve and sites like http://caniuse.com/ will give you some (though not all) the insight in to what technologies exist that can be used. Good luck!

Comment: You probably meant xhtml, not xml. They're 2 different things.

Comment: @Bálint XHTML is a subset of XML. When you change a local file to have a `.xhtml` extension it uses the browser's XML parser though the mime is `application/xhtml+xml`. Great stuff to code faster with higher quality. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
```

If your HTML document is not being styled correctly, then you need to make sure that href is pointing to the correct destination for your stylesheet.
If your stylesheet happens to the be in the same directory as your HTML file, you can use this to view it locally on your computer to make sure it is working as expected:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./main.css">
```

Also, did you actually copy your CSS into a separate file called main.css? Make sure you do that.